# Jquery Image Upload Script and PHP Sessions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I've succesfully implemented this script: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

(it uses jquery file upload )

The problem is that I am using the following PHP login script in conjection with it: http://phpsense.com/2006/php-login-script/

The image upload script calls an php file to delete/upload images via ajax.  I want to secure that php file so that only users who are logged in can access it (since my script is used by admins to update the site).

I included this in the php file called

```
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
    header("location: access-denied.php");
    exit();
}
```

When I try to access the page through the script it fails saying the session variable was NULL (the user wasn't logged in even though they were).

**The really strange thing is its random.**  If I keep refreshing the page over and over again it eventually succeeds in finding the session variable and loads the images.

The first thing I made sure was that the URL was consistent so  I am using the full URL for all my ajax calls so that isn't the issue....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this line of code :

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and see what it prints.then check queries on your browser.see if it can accept cookies or not

Comment: I don't think it's that nice to ask for an upvote. Let the community decide if the answer is worth it, people don't upvote in exchange for other upvotes

Comment: Okay I was able to monitor the var_dump and it just says "array(0) { }"

Comment: so there is a problem with your sessions.go to your tmp directory and see them your self

Comment: I hate to ask this, but  i'm fairly new to php and sessions in general, and i'm not sure what directory your talking about.  I didn't find a "PHPSessions" folder on my server but is always empty...

Comment: which server are you using? wamp , xampp , easyphp or what?